# Combine columns by header but keep duplicate rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have a script I am using to combine mutiple columns with the same header into one column. However, the script is deleting rows that have the same value in the first column. This script is meant to clean up my worksheet, so I would like to keep all rows of data and just tidy up the columns with duplicate headers.

```
    Dim source As Worksheet, target As Worksheet
    Dim uniques As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim current As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim found As New Scripting.Dictionary

    Set source = ActiveSheet
    Set target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("all data")
    Set current = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set found = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set uniques = New Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim row As Long, col As Long, targetRow As Long, targetCol As Long
    targetRow = 2
    targetCol = 1

    Dim activeVal As Variant
    For row = 1 To source.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    'Is the row a header row?
        If source.Cells(row, 1).Value2 = "WSTD_counts" Then
    'Reset the current column mapping.
            Set current = New Scripting.Dictionary
            For col = 1 To source.UsedRange.Columns.Count
                activeVal = source.Cells(row, col).Value2
                If activeVal <> vbNullString Then
                    current.Add col, activeVal
    'Do you already have a column mapped for it?
                    If Not found.Exists(activeVal) Then
                        found.Add activeVal, targetCol
                        targetCol = targetCol + 1
                    End If
                End If
            Next col
        Else
            activeVal = source.Cells(row, 1).Value2
    'New unique name?
            If Not uniques.Exists(activeVal) Then
        'Assign a row in the target sheet.
                uniques.Add activeVal, targetRow
                target.Cells(targetRow, 1).Value2 = activeVal
                targetRow = targetRow + 1
            End If
            For col = 1 To source.UsedRange.Columns.Count
        'Copy values.
                activeVal = source.Cells(row, col).Value2
                If source.Cells(row, col).Value2 <> vbNullString Then
                    target.Cells(uniques(source.Cells(row, 1).Value2), _
                                 found(current(col))).Value2 = activeVal
                End If
            Next col
        End If
    Next row

    'Write headers to the target sheet.
    target.Cells(1, 1).Value2 = "all data"
    For Each activeVal In found.Keys
        target.Cells(1, found(activeVal)).Value2 = activeVal
    Next activeVal

    'Delete part b & c data.
    Worksheets("all data").Range("a32:bk100").Clear

End Sub
```